# The program 'wget' can't download TWRP img

Tags: download, wget

I am using Windows 8.1 (Windows NT 6.2.9600) [I use wget for Windows, not gnuforwindows or something]. Could be that a problem? Also, if you don't know, the HTML file and the IMG file has the same name: twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img.html and twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img

```
wget -A img -r -l 1 -nd http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img --referer='http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img'
```

I thought it would accept only IMG files and ignore the HTML file with a setup referer, but instead, it disables SSL because it gets an error and stops the process

Answer (score 0):

You should use SSL/TLS, the site redirect to https. To avoid error use command like

```
wget -A img -r -l 1 -nd http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img \
--referer='http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img' --no-check-certificate
```

This will skip check of certificate

EDIT: Seems like your version have a bug or is too old and web server can't find common encryption schema to work (and redirect you to non SSL/TLS site)

EDIT2: If you want to use curl the command will be something like:

```
curl --referer 'http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img' -k http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img
```

Comment: `--2019-04-20 12:31:05--  http://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img
Resolving dl.twrp.me (dl.twrp.me)... 102.165.36.3
Connecting to dl.twrp.me (dl.twrp.me)|102.165.36.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img [following]
--2019-04-20 12:31:05--  https://dl.twrp.me/mido/twrp-3.3.0-0-mido.img
Disabling SSL due to encountered errors.
--2019-04-20 12:31:05--  http://%5C/
Resolving \\ (\\)... failed: No such host is known. .
wget: unable to resolve host address '\\'`

Comment: Maybe use curl?

Comment: @Tigran'sTips, you can try. Will add to answer how to use curl

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. The best solution is to switch to Linux. I have Windows To Go, so I'll just switch to Linux.